# How to deploy wso2 am-pattern-1 chart on Windows

Tags: kubernetes, wso2, kubernetes-helm, wso2-api-manager

I am trying to deploy the am-pattern-1 chart via helm on k8s as part of docker desktop on Windows but I am having difficulty with the mysql pod which is failing to start. I get this error in the pod log: `[ERROR] --initialize specified but the data directory has files in it. Aborting.`

I am pulling the chart directly from artifact hub, I am not deploying the chart from source locally, so I have not modified any configuration.  Commands used:

```
helm upgrade --install ingress-nginx ingress-nginx/ingress-nginx  
helm install apim-pattern1 wso2/am-pattern-1 --version 4.1.0-1
```

The PV and PVC are created and bound to the wso2am-mysql-db-service and the deployment is started in a completely new kubernetes cluster so should not contain any files.

Is this a known issue for k8s deployment on windows for this chart or is there a work around?

Appreciate any help on this issue.

Comment: What's the windows version and WSL version you use? This seems to be coming from the underlying mysql helm chart. We have not come across this issue during our testing.

Comment: Windows 10 Pro v10.0.19044 Build 19044 and WSL v2

Comment: According to https://github.com/docker-library/mysql/issues/757#issuecomment-1238859610, this seems to be an intermittent issue in different environments. Since this is not a known issue with our charts, only workaround would be to try in a completely different env (ubuntu or cloud)